# Viewing source-directories in elm-package

Tags: gulp, elm

Using elm 0.18.

How do you get elm to view all the modules in `src/` folder?  I have arranged my modules into directories, but I get errors like `I cannot find module 'ViewsUserLogin'` when I put a module into `src/views/user.`

I've added the files to `elm-package` in this fashion, but it still cannot find anything other than sibling files:

```
"source-directories": [
    "./src",
    "./src/views/",
    "./src/views/user/",
    ...
    "./dist"
],
```

Ultimately I would like to tell `elm-package` to look for all files inside `src/`.  How can I solve these problems?

Edit: I am also using gulp.

```
// gulpfile.js

var gulp = require('gulp');
var elm = require('gulp-elm');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

// File paths
var paths = {
  dest: 'dist',
  elm: 'src/*.elm',
  static: 'src/*.{html,css}'
};

// Init Elm
gulp.task('elm-init', elm.init);

// Compile Elm to HTML
gulp.task('elm', ['elm-init'], function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.elm)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(elm())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});

// Move static assets to dist
gulp.task('static', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.static)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});

// Watch for changes and compile
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.elm, ['elm']);
    gulp.watch(paths.static, ['static']);
});

// Local server
gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: 'dist',
        port: 3000
    });
});

// Main gulp tasks
gulp.task('build', ['elm', 'static']);
gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'build', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would capitalise your directories, and then you can use

```
import Views.User.ViewsUserLogin as ViewsUserLogin
```

And the top of ViewsUserLogin will need to read

```
module Views.User.ViewsUserLogin exposing (..)
```

(ps you may have your reasons for using gulp, but Elm supports hot loading with webpack which makes development much more streamlined - see for example https://github.com/simonh1000/elm-webpack-starter)

(pps Elm tends not not separate files out so much as javascript, and I've never done double nesting such as you are proposing even in large projects - might be worth you watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpDsk374LDE&t=1827s)

Comment: Excellent, didn't have to change anything in gulp or elm-package.  Looking into webpack and directory restructuring.  If I were to name one module `Views.User.Foo` and had another module `Views.Blog.Foo`, would there be a collision?

Comment: not at all. Either don't as the `as` and refer to everything fully qualified, or use e.g. `import Views.User.Foo as UserFoo`

Comment: Also, I just ran your webpack repo.  Pretty smooth.  Are there any other advantages of webpack over gulp for elm?